# Laravel model function best prickets

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4

im new in Laravel , I have an issue as below
I make in category model query to check is category is exist or not
as below

```
 public function scopeIsExist($query ,$id)
    {
        return $query->where(['deleted' => 1, 'id' => $id])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
    }
```

and my controller is

```
    public function edit($id)
    {


        $dataView['category'] = Category::IsExist($id);    

        if(!$dataView['category'])
        {
            return view('layouts.error');
        }else{
            $dataView['title'] = 'name';
            $dataView['allCategories'] = Category::Allcategories()->get();
            return  view('dashboard.category.edit')->with($dataView);
        }

    }
```

my problem is when I use method `isEXIST` if id not found it not redirect to error page  but ween i remove `ISEXIST` AND replace it as below

```
$dataView['category'] = Category::where(['deleted' => 1, 'id' => $id])->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->first();
```

it work well .
can any one help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because local scope should return an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder`.  You should remove the `first()` in the scope and put it in the controller.
Redefine your scope like so:

```
public function scopeIsExist($query ,$id)
    {
        return $query->where(['deleted' => 1, 'id' => $id])->orderBy('id', 'DESC');
    }
```

In your controller edit method:

```
    $dataView['category'] = Category::IsExist($id)->first();
```

You can have a look to the doc for local scopes https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#local-scopes